# how do I fix error when parsing dates that have mm/dd/yyyy 0:00:00 format with lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to parse a vector of timestamps formatted mm/dd/yyyy_hh:mm:ss with lubridate using mdy_hms().

All the dates parsed correctly, except 10/1/2018 0:00:00

I tried adding truncated=2 to the lubridate call, which often solves the problem of incomplete entries, but that didn't work either.

I'm guessing the problem is with the 0:00:00 (it's the only one in the vector with all zeroes), every other date I try with zeroes has the same issue.

```
mdy_hms(10/1/2018 0:00:00)
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "mdy_hms(10/1/2018 00"

mdy_hms(10/1/2018 00:00:00, truncated = 2)
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "mdy_hms(10/1/2018 00"
```

Comment: You are missing the quotes:  `mdy_hms("10/1/2018 0:00:00")`

Comment: Shouldn't the argument be a quoted string? `mdy_hms("10/1/2018 0:00:00")` - otherwise its not valid syntax.

Comment: Oops I forgot the quotations in the example code. That date still didn't parse in the vector - until I tried truncated = 3 (instead of 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi carlite I can't replicate your variable there is no (10/1/2018 0:00:00), I don't believe R is even capable of creating something like that, when I enclose it with "" it works fine.

```
library(lubridate)
# Maybe you were put off by the choice of "hiding" the hms info.

mdy_hms("10/1/2018 00:00:00") + 1
```